# Passive voice with the verb in front

Tags: passive-voice

Is it possible to write a sentence in English with the verb before the passive subject?

If so, please provide examples.

Comment: A very common mistake for English learners coming from Brazilian Portuguese is to write e.g. "It was paid the suppliers" when they mean "The suppliers were paid", because in Brazilian Portuguese there is a widely use passive construction with the verb in front.

Comment: There’s a big difference between what ***can*** be done and what ***should*** be done:  Shot was he by the policeman.

Comment: But you can make that sentence perfectly acceptable by adding ***to***:  “*It was paid **to** the suppliers.*” which could be the response to the question, “Where did that payment go?” or “To whom was that payment issued?”

Comment: Deos this work?  "Renewed shall be the blade that was broken"

Comment: “It was paid *to* the suppliers.” But now _suppliers_ is no longer the passive subject, is it?

Comment: Right. I was just stating how that sentence could be made to be acceptable with a slight modification, not that doing so would maintain the passive, verb-first nature of the sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various constructions in English where the verb or the auxiliary precedes the subject; but since passives in English always require an auxiliary, it is almost always only the auxiliary and not the main verb which may precede the subject.

Occasionally in poetry, or very old-fashioned writing, writers will alter the syntax further. For example the 1896 translation of a [mediaeval bestiary](http://bestiary.ca/beasts/beast146.htm) contains the sentence:

> Never was seen another such a beast, for it lives on land and in water.

I don't believe you will find such an instance without an initial adverbial or adverbial phrase ("Never" in that example).

Comment: Where seldom is heard a discouraging word,
And the sky is not cloudy all day.  - Home on the Range.

Comment: As I said, in poetry. And with an initial adverbial ("seldom").

Answer (score 1):

Of course:

> Through the good offices of the embassy was arranged a new passport, a replacement visa, and a letter of introduction to the foreign minister.

Comment: This is interesting, because I have a feeling that the word *there* has been elided, between *embassy* and *was*. And If I say *there was arranged a new passport* - is *passport* the subject? If it is then I can think of endless instances where the passive verb precedes the subject.

Comment: @WS2 I think they're different structures, but if *passport* is the subject, what's *there*?

Comment: It calls for a grammarian (such as @Colin Fine), which sadly I am not. But equally one could say *Lying on the table was a passport*. I think *lying on the table* is an adverbial phrase which complements the verb *was*. It seems to me to be doing the same thing as *there* in my earlier example. However *there* in *there was a mouse in the house*, seems to be performing the same function as *it* in *it was raining*.

Comment: @WS2 Yes, I agree that *Lying on the table* is an adverbial locative modifying *was* and that *there* in *there was a mouse* is not (it's a dummy subject).  I think *there* in *There was arranged a new passport* is more like the latter than the former.  It means "it came about" more than pointing to some place where passports are arranged.